# Stop Galleria from looping slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, galleria

I have the latest version of Galleria (1.2.6), I'm using the Classic theme with Picasa plugin. I have set the slideshow on autoplay, however I would like the slideshow to STOP after playing through all the images. Also, I would like Galleria to stop/return to the first image - is there a way to do that?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Provide us link of Galleria Picasa link which you are using...

Comment: picasa: 'useralbum:110151686478277507568/index'

Answer (score 3):

You should add this code after loading the gallery:

```
var gallery = Galleria.get(0)

var totalImages = parseInt(gallery.$('total').html());

gallery.bind("loadfinish", function(e) {
    if (e.index == 0 || e.index == totalImages - 1) {
        gallery.pause();
    }
});
```

It first gets the gallery (assuming you only have one gallery in your page) and the total image count. Then, every time an image is loaded, checks if the image is the first or the last one, and pauses the gallery if so.

**EDITED:**

You should add this script after the js are loaded in a `<script>` tag:

```
// Note .js names might be different in your page
<script type="text/javascript" src="galleria-1.2.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="galleria.classic.theme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="galleria.picassa.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Above code here...
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the reply. Sorry for asking a stupid question, but there are three js linked to my page(galleria 1.2.5 ; galleria classic theme ; galleria picasa), I'm not sure which document I should insert these lines and where in the document exactly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can add a new script tag after the .js are loaded with the code in it :)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the "next picture" and "previous picture" buttons from looping as well? (so in the last picture, the "next" button doesn't go to the first picture and in the first picture the "previous" button doesn't work either).